# Android game, options about storing user data

Tags: java, android, file, save, format

I'm developing a little game for android and i'm at the point where i want to save data of the progress the user has made so far.

I read about sharedpreferences, SQLlite... i have used some XML parsers aswell but my question is, if i want this:

- Fast performance.
- Secure or encryptable.

I want to point out that the data to save is not very long, profile name, levels completed, faction selected...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: faster? SQLite... quick to achieve? Shared. I'll go for the SQLite option (is more flexible). For the security thing, both cases users can get access to data if they're root users. In that case, sensitive data could be encrypted with base64 or similar.

Comment: I will go for shared then, thanks!

Comment: if you wish, I've done a quick shared library [KeySaver](https://github.com/mkiisoft/KeySaver) to have an easy implementation of Shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any solution will be "fast enough" for loading/saving the data...  and any of them will be encryptable (as in they can all store string data).

SharedPreferences would probably be the simplest way to go.  Perhaps store your data as JSON, then store the entire JSON string in SharedPreferences.  Then you can easily add encryption to it later.

Comment: True... but a lot of memory usage to save JSON to String to Shared, to String, to JSON, to edit, to encrypt, to (return to 1st part) I think SQLite is better option... simply update the item you need (encrypted) and query as you wish. But yes, it would take a lot more time to develop.